# Which of the two is correct, the employees or employees?

Tags: grammar

The code-based approach to office ethics enables [ the employees / employees ] to know up front what is morally required and expected of them at work.

Which of the two is correct when it means employees in general?  Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Answer (score 1):

Although both your examples are grammatically correct, it is more likely in context that you would simply refer to **employees**.

However, you might include the article **the** if you had previously referred to either **employees** or **the employees**, as in:

> All employees will be expected to familiarise themselves with the code-based approach to office ethics. This approach enables **the employees** to know up front what is morally required and expected of them at work.

Here the article **the** serves to reflect your previous reference to the employees concerned.

However, it works just as well if you omit the article. It's really a matter of preference.